# Moving View with setLeft or setPadding

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, android-linearlayout

I would like to swipe a View in a LinearLayout, and I use view.setLeft(value) to position dynamically my view.
But the view is vibrating when I swipe it. 
So I decided to try with view.setPadding(value,0,0,0) and it stops to vibrate but now I get another problem. The view's width reduces itself in my LinearLayout and the view's height gets bigger. And I would like that my view conserves its size.

This is my view that I add with an adapter in my LinearLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_picture" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewAdd"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewAdd" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use something like this [library](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView), or this [one](https://coderwall.com/p/dpfrcw/swipelistview-open-source-library-for-android).

Comment: The first library that you give me looks good, but it works with ListView. Do you think it is going to work with LinearLayout ?

Comment: Now I am using ListView and that works properly with the first library, thanks.